# pass the dynamically selected dropdown's id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ddl_SelectedIndexchanged function in javascript which accepts an argument that is a dropdownlist as like the following code in vb.net

```
Private Sub ddl_SelectedIndexchanged(drop as dropdownlist)
   'code
End sub
```

my javascript code as same as the above

```
function ddl_SelectedIndexchanged(drop)
{
   //code
}
```

now i am going to call the function on document.ready 
But in my page i have 5 dropdownlist, consider ddl1,ddl2,ddl3,ddl4,ddl5

if the ddl1 selected then there will be a seperated code for it.
if ddl2 selected that also has a seperated code.
but if the both will not get selected, then any of the other will have access on the ddl_selectedIndexchanged() function.
Since "any of the other" means dynamic selection i dont know how to pass the (ddl) argument as the following

```
if(ddl1.selectedIndex == 0)
    ddl_selectedIndexChanged(ddl2);
else if(ddl2.selectedIndex == 0)
    ddl_selectedIndexChanged(ddl1);
else
    ddl_selectedIndexChanged(`dynamic selection of ddl3,ddl4,ddl5`);
```

Comment: what code you are using to create drop-down list? do you know about jQuery well? you said different functions so you have three callback functions 1,2 -> first and second and 3 -> the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select class="ddcommon" name="dd1">
    <!-- Your options -->
</select>

<select class="ddcommon" name="dd2">
    <!-- Your options -->
</select>

<select class="ddcommon" name="dd3">
    <!-- Your options -->
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // Code requires jquery
    $(function(){

        $('.ddcommon').change(function(e) {

            element_name  = $(this).attr('name');
            element_value = $(this).val();

            switch(element_name) { // start switch

                case 'dd1':
                    // your code
                    break;

                case 'dd2':
                    // your code
                    break;

                case 'dd3':
                    // your code
                    break;                                  

                // .... so on cases

                    } // endswitch
            });
    });
</script>
```